# overlap cardview over image

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming and I am trying to slide my view over image.This is my code(Not sure if this is the right way)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ron"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/cv">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/person_age"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I want to scroll my cardview over image keeping image fixed.something like eclipsing the image.
[image]

and after scrolling completely the image should get hidden.(I dont want it to flow under toolbar)

[image]

Comment: And where is the Scrollview?

Answer (score 1):

Try to place your `CardView` into `ScrollView` and add `CardView`'s `marginTop` which equals to your `Image`'s height.

Comment: It's scrollable but it looks like the image is still der and I am scrolling underneath it..do u have any link or example to point to?